# Trying to convert nested JSON file to CSV in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I am trying to convert the nested JSON file to CSV file using PowerShell and not able to find the correct logic.
This is my example JSON file content:

```
[
    {
        "Device":  "Device1",
        "Test":  [
                     {
                         "IP":  "10.20.3.6",
                         "Result":  "Fail"
                     }
                 ]
    },
    {
        "Device":  "Device2",
        "Test":  [
                     {
                         "IP":  "10.124.102.100",
                         "Result":  "Fail"
                     },
                     {
                         "IP":  "107.12.13.51",
                         "Result":  "Fail"
                     }
                 ]
    }
]
```

The code I am trying

```
$JsonData = Get-Content '.\Report_202104262250.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json  $JsonData | Select-Object -Property Device, @{Name = 'IP'; Expression = { foreach ($ip in $_.Test.IP) {$ip} }}, @{Name = 'Result'; Expression = {$_.Test.Result}}
```

This is the csv output I am looking for

```
Device  Test__IP        Test__Result
Device1 10.20.3.6       Fail
Device2 10.124.102.100  Fail
Device2 107.12.13.51    Fail
```

Tried other help resources but could not achieve it. Please help needed.

Comment: What did you try to do? What is the script that you tried to write? We are here to help, not to do it for you :)

Comment: I have tried this code `$JsonData = Get-Content '.\Report_202104262250.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json 
$JsonData | Select-Object -Property Device, @{Name = 'IP'; Expression = { foreach ($ip in $_.Test.IP) {$ip} }}, @{Name = 'Result'; Expression = {$_.Test.Result}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Load the json and convert to objects
$json = Get-Content .\json.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Create custom objects
$json | ForEach-Object {
    $Device = $_.Device
    # Iterate through each of the tests and create object for each
    $_.Test | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Device'       = $Device
            'Test__IP'     = $_.IP
            'Test__Result' = $_.Result
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\Test_Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```